# Dynamic bounty ad is broken

Tags: bug, community-promotion-ads

The dynamic ad for bounties for a site is currently broken on movies.se. I haven't checked on other sites but I assume they are also broken.

Here's what it currently looks like on movies: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2618/52

Comment: Yeah, the ads must be hosted on the SE imgur, I think, which is the problem. My understanding is that none of these work any more. Second bullet point on the list of rules: *Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)*

Comment: AFAIK, that dynamic ad is not actually maintained by Stack Exchange. Rather, it's a third-party Heroku app [written by some folks over at apple.SE](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1873/how-does-the-active-bounties-banner-work) (and later adopted by a bunch of other sites as well). To get it fixed, we really need to contact the maintainer(s) of the app somehow; alas, I'm not 100% sure who they are.

Comment: This ad has nothing to do with us. We don't host or maintain it. The server that normally generates them is throwing a 500 Internal Server Error. Likely something broken on their side.

Comment: @Catija: That imgur hosting requirement has always been there, but I don't think it has ever been actually enforced by the system.

Comment: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/932/community-promotion-ads-2012/998#998 @IlmariKaronen?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the original appearance, @Catija. Looks like it was written by [Kyle Cronin](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13/kyle-cronin); I've pinged him at the meta.apple.SE post you linked to. I found [the Github repo](https://github.com/kylecronin/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad), too.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen  Last seen Sep 26 '16 at 19:30 Ugh... hope everything's ok. Ah, March 30th on SO... so not too bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up! This issue has been fixed. [rand al'thor](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/community-promotion-ads-2017/2618#comment10588_2618) was correct that it was an HTTP vs HTTPS issue.

[image]

Comment: What, no postmorten about the issue?

Comment: Hey Kyle! Someone has a question for you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310787/there-are-active-bounties Not sure you have an answer but figured you were the person to ask.