# There are _ _ active bounties, but what when there are more than 99?

Tags: support, bounties, external-sources

I recently saw this on a Stack Exchange site:
[image]

I'm just curious(and this may actually happen in the future), but what would happen to the image if there were more than 99 bounties?

Comment: That image is created and maintained by a user, not by the SE network, so only they can answer the question, I think.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an entirely user-created image, and not about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Oh, I'm sorry, I did not know this. Should I delete my question then?

Comment: Not necessary; maybe the owner of that image can comment here.

Comment: I've pinged the creator [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294958/dynamic-bounty-ad-is-broken#comment1015355_294973). They've not been on MSE recently but they've used SO within the last month.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog not sure why it needs closing? It isn't tagged as bug? And a user maintains the image is a valid answer.

Comment: @rene This isn't something that the SE team can address.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for the ping! I've answered below.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog so what? There are lots of questions here that can't be addressed by the SE team.

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: @JohnMiliter I saw this on Chemistry Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JohnMiliter it's one of the [Community Promotion Ads](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/community-promotion-ads-2018). :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears it stops displaying at 99, there are currently 360 questions with a bounty on Stack Overflow and when the URL is changed to point at SO it displays like this:

http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/stackoverflow.com/bounty.png

[image: Active Bounties]

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 13):

PeterJ is correct, the counter stops at 99 because the number of digits is fixed at exactly two. I recommend against using this community ad on large sites that routinely have more than 99 active bounties as it obviously won't be showing the correct number during those times.

Comment: Hey, I noticed that your application to serve these bounty ads has been giving a server error for a while now. Are you still planning on maintaining it, or is it dead now?